# Cannot create a second Dictionary Property inside the class

Tags: .net, vb.net

clsFile has 2 dictionaries, however, in constructor first dictionary is always create, but the second dictionary ends up being Nothing

Dictionaries are identical (Of Long, clsEmployee); but previously I tried making second one (of Long, clsCondition) and (Of String, clsCondoition) - to no avail.  classes clsEmployee and clsCondition are also objects in the code.

Code for clsFile:

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions


Public Class clsFile


'-- CLASS LOCAL VARIABLES DECLARATION
Private cnDB As SqlConnection
Private m_Number As String
Private m_Auditor As clsEmployee
Private m_User As clsEmployee
Private m_Reviewer As clsEmployee
Private m_FileTypeId As Long
Private m_ReviewStatusId As Long
Private m_ActionDTTM As Date
Private m_SelectDTTM As Date
Private m_ReviewDTTM As Date

Private m_inAudit As Boolean
Private m_ReviewersDict As Dictionary(Of Long, clsEmployee)
Private m_ConditionsDict As Dictionary(Of Long, clsEmployee)


**************************************PROPERTIES***********************************

  Public Property Reviewers() As Dictionary(Of Long, clsEmployee)
    Get
        Reviewers = m_ReviewersDict

    End Get

    Set(ByVal ReviewersDict As Dictionary(Of Long, clsEmployee))
        m_ReviewersDict = ReviewersDict
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Conditions() As Dictionary(Of Long, clsEmployee)
    Get
        Conditions = m_ConditionsDict

    End Get

    Set(ByVal ConditionsDict As Dictionary(Of Long, clsEmployee))
        m_ConditionsDict = Conditions
    End Set
End Property
```

*****************************CONSTRUCTOR**************************************

```
 Public Sub New(*arguments provided*)
    number= strLoanNumber

    Me.Reviewer = New clsEmployee(RVWR_ID)
    Me.Reviewer.Dept.Id = RBW_Dept_ID
    Me.Auditor = New clsEmployee(AUD_ID)
    Me.User = New clsEmployee(USR_ID)

    Me.Reviewers = New Dictionary(Of Long, clsEmployee)
    Me.Conditions = New Dictionary(Of Long, clsEmployee) 

    cnDB = SQLcn


End Sub
```

---

`
when stepping through the code - Me.Conditions = nothing even after constructor has run. I use VB.net, VS2005.

Any ideas why?
thanks!

Comment: Why do you ue this old VB6 way to return values from a method/property? Use `Return` instead. Not sure if this causes your issue though. So instead of `Conditions = m_ConditionsDict` in the getter use `Return m_ConditionsDict`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Why did you not ask about VS2005? Should be on VS2008 at least, 2005 is buggy, from what I heard.

Answer (score 2):

Surely

```
Set(ByVal ConditionsDict As Dictionary(Of Long, clsEmployee))
        m_ConditionsDict = Conditions
End Set
```

should be

```
Set(ByVal ConditionsDict As Dictionary(Of Long, clsEmployee))
        m_ConditionsDict = ConditionsDict
End Set
```

?